# Dropdown-Select for a database table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, drop-down-menu

I simply want to have a dropdown menu which will have all the rows of a table as its choices. How do I achieve that?
Let's say I have a model "Student" and I want to have the "name" property to be displayed in the choices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Use [select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select), for example:

```
select(:model, :attribute, Student.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but when I copy-pasted that line, I got nothing.(assuming I should have left model and attribute as they are in the piece of code you gave)

Comment: No, you should replace :model with the model you're creating a form for, and :attribute replace with model attribute used for this select. Please provide the form code.

Comment: sorry for not understanding it but i still got some questions: why do we need 'attribute' exactly? you mean the value(attribute of the model) which i wanna pass?. and what's the last part of the code{|p| [ p.name, p.id ] })?

Comment: attribute is needed in order to put the selected value to the corresponding column of the database table. For a more precise answer I need more details - where do you use a drop-down list and for what. Also show me the code of your form

Comment: well to be honest, i don't have the form yet because i am not sure if i need a form. right now i just wanted to display that dropdown. i don't need to do anything with the database: not doing an insert. i just neeed the dropdown so i will know what to display depending on the choice in the dropdown

Comment: Ok then. Put this code in a view: <%= select_tag('student', options_for_select(Student.all.collect { |s| s.name })) %>

Answer (score 2):

Here is some info on using collection selects...

http://www.fmhcc.com.au/ruby/rails/using-collection_select-in-rails/